# How to add an item to a list in python and save it

Tags: python

My program is set up so I can add items to the lists from terminal but whenever I do this for example `myFile.append('hello')` it keeps it there but when I exit terminal and do it again `'hello'` is deleted. Please help. Thank you!

Code

```
elif userInput in command:
    print("Okay, Initializing new command.\n\n")
    command1 = raw_input("Which command would you like to add?\nKeyword\nLater Versions\n ").lower()
    if command1 == 'keyword':
        print('You selected keyword, to exit press enter')
        command2 = raw_input("Which Keyword would you like to edit? ")
        if command2 == 'calc':
            command3 = raw_input("Which Keyword would you like to add? ")
            calc.append(command3)
            print(calc)
```

Comment: Please include your code in your question. This will make it much easier for us to help.

Comment: In all programming languages variables (or lists or dictionaries or whatever) all exist only in the program's memory and are cleaned up when the program exits.  If you want to save something you have to put it in a database or a file or some other external storage method.

Comment: @Cfreak. A startup file saved in the current directory might work too...

Comment: So is `calc` the list that you want to persist when you exit the terminal and open again?

Comment: @elethan I want the code to be written inside of the list I have at the beginning of the source code. Thank yoU!

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: See my second update. That's about all I can do. Hope you get things working the way you want!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
with open(myFile, 'a') as f:
    f.write('hello')
```

You can append to a list with`.append` but not a file. Instead, you can use the 'a' flag as above to append to the file `myFile` where `myFile` is a file path.

## Update:

Based on your existing code and what you want to achieve, try this:

```
...


elif userInput in command:
    print("Okay, Initializing new command.\n\n")
    command1 = raw_input("Which command would you like to add?\nKeyword\nLater Versions\n ").lower()
    if command1 == 'keyword':
        print('You selected keyword, to exit press enter')
        command2 = raw_input("Which Keyword would you like to edit? ")
        if command2 == 'calc':
            command3 = raw_input("Which Keyword would you like to add? ")
            calc = 'path/to/file'
            with open(calc, 'a+') as f:
                f.write(command3 + '\n')
                f.seek(0) #This brings you back to the start of the file, because appending will bring it to the end
                print(f.readlines())
```

Basically, you are writing to a file, and printing back a list of all the words written to that file. The `'a+'` flag will let you open a file for reading and writing. Also, instead of/in addition to printing the "list" with `print(f.readlines())`, you could assign it to a variable and have an actual python `list` object for manipulating later, if that is what you want: `wordlist = f.readlines()`.

Also, to improve your fundamental understanding of the issue, you should probably check out [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

## Update 2

If you need to have a Python `list` of keywords earlier in your code you could add:

```
 with open('wordlist.txt', 'a+') as f: #wordlist.txt can be changed to be another file name or a path to a file
     f.seek(0) #opening with `'a+'` because it will create the file if it does not exist, 
               # and seeking because `'a+'` moves to the end of the file 
     calc = f.readlines()
```

This will read a list of words from `wordlist.txt` and save them to an Python `list` called `calc`. Now since `calc` is an actual Python `list` object, you can use `calc.append('whatever')`. Later in your code, when you want to save all the keywords back to the persistent "list" (which is actually just a text file with words separated by newline (`'\n'`), you can do:

```
with open('wordlist.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for word in calc:
        f.write(word)
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines())
```

This will overwrite your wordlist file with all the words currently in the `calc` list, and print out all the values to the console.

This is as good as I can do without really understanding how your program is supposed to work or writing it myself. Try to improve your understanding of Python file I/O; it is not so complicated with some practice, and will serve you well in the future for simple persistent data. I would also suggest going through a Python tutorial like [this one](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python) on Codecademy to improve your general understanding of how Python works. I don't mean that as an insult; I did this tutorial myself a while ago, and it really helped me to create a good foundation of Python fundamentals. It also includes [a lesson on file I/O](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-intermediate-en-OGNHh/0/1?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096). Good luck!

Comment: Also, given OP's question, I think you will have to provide waaaay more information before this answer is useful to them.

Comment: I won't downvote this since its not "wrong" but I'm not sure its all that helpful to OP.   OP needs a very basic tutorial to understand the differences between storage and memory.

Comment: Can I make it add something to a list like that? or a specific line?

Comment: @HelloName This answer will take whatever you put in the `f.write()` and put it into a text file. It will not be a `list` by Python's definition, however, you could read the file into a `list` data type when you'd like to access it and do things with it. If that's something that you'd like to do let me know and I could walk you through it. It's quite simple.

Comment: @HelloName you should update your question to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. The code in my answer will allow for simple data persistence, and you can use it to save a "list" of words, and even transfer it back to a python `list` object, if that is what you want to do. But I am not totally clear as to what you want to do exactly. I just tried to answer as best I could based on existing question.

Comment: @Harrison if this comment is meant for OP, make sure to tag them. If you are offering to explain it to me, that is not necessary, and I was considering adding it to my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @elethan It was meant for OP, sorry I forgot to add the tag.

Comment: @Harrison Hi thank you for your answers. I want it so that it adds it to a list object inside of the code. I have updated my question with the bit of code I am working on. Thank you :D

Comment: @elethan Hi thank you for your answers. I want it so that it adds it to a list object inside of the code. I have updated my question with the bit of code I am working on. Thank you :D

Comment: @HelloName I am working on updating my answer so it is more informative

Comment: @elethan Thanks for the updated post but now the terminal is saying no such file or directory: path/to/file

Comment: @HelloName you have to specify a path on your file system. I just have that path as a generic example.

Comment: @elethan but will that go to the list i want to edit?

Comment: If `calc` in the example code below points to a file, then yes it should. Try just changing that path to `wordlist.txt` and it will write your commands to a file with that name in the same directory as your source code. Just try it and see what it does, and tweak to fit your specific needs.

Comment: @elethan calc is the list. calc = ['blah','blah'] so i want to add more things to the list but whenever i do calc.append('blah') it deletes it after I close the terminal